# Typescript and 'initialise only' type imports?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How should we manage imports that are only there to directly initialise functionality?

For example:

```
import GeoJSON from 'mongoose-geojson-schema';
import mongoose, { Model } from 'mongoose';

const AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   'coordinates': mongoose.Schema.Types.Point
});
```

This results in a "'mongoose-geojson-schema' is declared but its value is never read" error, even though it needs to be there to initialise the functionality in mongoose.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `GeoJSON is declared but its value is never read`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple: `import 'mongoose-geojson-schema';`

---

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only)

> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values.